# How do I upgrade matplotlib python 3 version in Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to graph in a Jupyter Notebook using matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

array1 = np.random.rand(5)
array2 = np.random.rand(5)
plt.plot(array1, array2)
plt.show()
```

and I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.colors' has no attribute 'to_rgba'
```

I googled the error and it says I need to upgrade my matplotlib version. I have tried several ways to do it. 
    `sudo pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib`,
    `python3 -m pip install -U matplotlib` and
    `python -m pip install -U matplotlib`.
I always get the following error:

```
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9ncad8jg/matplotlib/
```

In order to solve that error I have tried,
    `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`
and try to upgrade matplotlib but I still have the same error.

I haven't been able to upgrade the matplotlib, I still have version 1.5.1 and I need the latest version!

Comment: Show us the output of `whereis python` and `which python`

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you mean. what is the whereis python output and the which python output?

Comment: `whereis python` and `which python` are commands https://maker.pro/linux/tutorial/basic-linux-commands-for-beginners